# node/add page shows 2 of every type. How do I fix this?

Tags: nodes, users

My node/add page (Add Content) shows two of every content type!

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

I am 99% sure this is is a database problem, but my database node_type table looks OK and only has one of each type.

I have disabled every module I could, updated everything, and have no errors in the log.

When I point my installation at a fresh database I do not have the problem.  When I point a fresh Drupal installation at my current database I do have the problem.  It seems like database to me.

Using Drupal 7.15.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I've fixed it.

The problem was that the table menu_links had duplicates in it for the content types.  How they got there, I have no idea.

The fix is to find the menu_links table using phpMyAdmin and search for the links there were duplicates of (title link_field using LIKE %...% operator). Then simply, drop them from the table.  The reason is because the node/add page is just a page (or Overlay) view of the items in the "Add content" menu.

Answer (score 2):

I'm facing the same issue but solved it by following these steps.

Go to *admin/structure/menu/manage/navigation* and check the links, if links are duplicated there then delete one of the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

I think they are duplicated in your database.
see contents of `node_type` table in your database, and remove duplicated record.

Comment: I've checked node_type.  There is only one of each type there.  I've also tried exporting the node_type table, delete it, then re-import it and the problem persists.

Comment: I've also added a column to the node_type table.  Edited one of the rows to add some data into that column.  Refreshed caches in Drupal. Then deleted that column.  Still no go.  (I was hoping maybe the last column had some bad data in its field...nope.)